# Is the 30-day lifetime of a custom dataproc image temporary?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-images specifies that

> The custom image is saved in Cloud Compute Images, and is valid to create a Cloud Dataproc cluster for 30 days. You must re-create the custom image to reuse it after the 30-day period.

Is that limitation temporary while the custom image feature is in beta, or will it be perpetual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perpetual limitation, which will be present after custom images will go to GA (General Availability).

If you have a feedback on how and why this is impacting your use case you can send it to dataproc-feedback@google.com for Dataproc team consideration.

Comment: OK Thanks! We will just have to remember making a new image every now and then as this image will serve for nightly automatic cluster creation.